# Ubuntu update overwrote (almost) entire home directory

Tags: gnome, updates, 18.04, filesystem, lvm

Sorry for the indescriptive title and lack of technical details, but I'm absolutely puzzled about what's going on:

Today, a update for GNOME Ubuntu 18.04 was installed on my machine. The update, however, did not finish with the usual dialogue about restarting the system but displayed the dialogue you get when starting Ubuntu for the first time (selection of keyboard layout, enable/disable location services, etc.), the system then froze.

I restarted the machine and now almost all files in my home directory (and any other user's) are gone.
The files that are still there are a single git repository inside ~/git (there have been 40+) and parts of miniconda inside ~/miniconda3/lib. I don't really see a pattern there.

I have absolutely no idea where to start or what additional information I can provide.

Edit: I used TestDisk to browse my volumes and found that the files are still present on /dev/dm-0 (or /dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root) but not on /dev/sda. Is there any way to restore the mapping?

Comment: You really need to report this against the updater on bugzilla.

Comment: Yes, I will do that.

Comment: Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1789003